# AJAX vs Fragment Caching for W3 Total Cache

Tags: ajax, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm running a WP site with WooCommerce and I want to do some caching. I'm going to exclude the pages such as the cart/checkout for obvious reasons however there are a couple of the things on the site I would like to stay dynamic and not be cached.

An example is the number of items in the cart and there's also a block of html that displays differently whether you're logged in or not.

So my question is, should I load these via AJAX or should I define them as fragments using mfunc? What are the advantages and benefits for each and which one is recommended for this task?

Comment: Good question, have you found any answer for it somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: How many hits do you get on the site?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a friend of link only answers, but as I can't bind the whole source code + explanation in here, I'll just leave a link to @Rarst [Fragment Cache Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/Rarst/fragment-cache).